# Granting code in EC2 instance access to S3 bucket of another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS accounts: A and B.

I uploaded a piece of Python code to an Amazon EC2 instance running in Account A. I want to put an object into the S3 bucket of Account B through this Python code.

How can I set it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in few ways.

#### Assume Role method

The IAM Role of EC2A can assume a `roleB` in AccountB to upload file to S3 in AccountB. This is the recommended method. because the credentials does not need to be stored or hard coded.

1. This method requires the instance in Account A to have an IAM role assigned. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/
2. Allow the IAM role we created in step 1 to assume a role (lets call it Role B) in account B. you need to create an IAM policy and assign it to the IAM role.

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/RoleB"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. In the Account B, you need to create the role B
4. setup a trust policy in role B to allow any user, group or role on Account A to assume role B

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:root"
       },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
     }]
   }
   ```

   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/edit_trust.html
5. Finally, you need to assign an IAM policy to the role B that gives S3 access.

   ```
   {
     "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
     "Properties": {
       "PolicyName": "S3WritePolicy",
       "PolicyDocument": {
         "Statement": [
           {
             "Action": "s3:PutObject",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Resource": "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

#### Using direct credentials

The python code can include a credential that directly give it permissions to upload file to S3 in Account B. To do this, You can create a user in the IAM of Account B and use the credential directly on the python code.

```
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='access key',
    aws_secret_access_key='secret key')
```

Reference:
how to create iam user - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: What are the credentials and vpcb? I don't quite understand

Comment: i know it is too big answer. sorry about it. Because `Assume role` is the best method to do this. But if you want to easily get it done, you can simply create an IAM User account B with programatic access. Then you can simply use it from your python code.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

The main requirement is that the code running on the Amazon EC2 instance has **credentials** that permit access to the Amazon S3 bucket in Account B. (I will assume that the bucket does *not* have public access turned on.)

The best practice method of providing credentials to an application running on an Amazon EC2 instance is to **assign an IAM Role to the instance**. This will automatically provide a set of credentials to applications on the instance that are using the AWS SDK. (For Python, this would be the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) SDK.)

The IAM Role should have, at minimum, permission to use Amazon S3 in the target bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, while this permits the IAM Role from Account A to call the bucket in Account B, Account A cannot actually grant access to resources Account B. Only Account B can permit access to resources in Account B.

It might sound confusing, but:

- The IAM Role in Account A needs to be allowed to *call* S3, *AND*
- Account B must permit the role from Account A to access resources in Account B

The simplest way to achieve the second bullet would be to **add a Bucket Policy** to the bucket in Account B that permits the IAM Role from Account A permission to use the bucket.

The bucket policy would look something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"  <-- Change this
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, when creating the object in Account B, it is vital to **use an ACL of `bucket-owner-full-control`**. This hands-over control of the object to Account B. If this is not done, then Account B will not be able to access (or even delete!) the object.

So, in Python, your code would look similar to:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.upload_file(
    Filename='/tmp/foo.txt',
    Bucket='my-bucket',
    Key='foo.txt',
    ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'}
)
```

Comment: Extra info: Just because an Amazon EC2 instance is _running_ in Account A does not prevent it from using credentials from Account B. So, another option would be to create an IAM User in Account B, generate an Access Key/Secret Key for that user, then store those credentials in the EC2 instance using `aws configure`. Thus, the Python application can directly use resources in Account B. It does not matter that the virtual machine itself was launched in Account A.